# Save answer of a query in a variable PL/SQL

Tags: function, plsql, sqldatatypes

I want to save the answer from the query into a variable, which I then go through and check the individual values.

```
FUNCTION F_capa(
v_carId car.carid%Type,
v_snumber box.snumber%Type)
  RETURN Boolean
IS
 
 type t_box is Table OF box%rowtype;
 v_possibleBox t_box := t_box();
 
BEGIN
 SELECT  b.carid, COUNT(p.trayID) AS amaunt,b.capacity ,b.date
 INTO  v_possibleBox
 FROM Box b
 left JOIN place p on b.carID = p.carID
 WHERE b.snumber = v_snumber
 GROUP BY b.carID, b.date, b.capacity ;
 
 --  LOOP IF(  v_carId = v_possibleBox(i).carID)  Something like that

 End;
```

But I always get this error.

```
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

I am relatively new to PLSQL and really doubt this site, so i would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-00947 is telling you that the values returned by your query and the v_possibleBox record don't match.  The obvious problem is the amaunt column you create.  The t_box type has the same structure as your table (in fact you don't really need it, it's just an alias for box%rowtype) and that table won't have a column amaunt.

In this case you might do better using a Cursor for loop, this has the following structure:

```
FOR record IN (select_statement)
LOOP
    process_record_statements;
END LOOP;
```

record becomes a record with a type that matches the columns returned by your select statement, so inside the loop record.amaunt will work.  You don't have to call the record record BTW so `for myName IN (select statement)` is fine.

If you want to use the original construct then you need to define `t_box` so that it has the same columns and types as returned by the SQL.

Comment: thank you sir, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if you posted more info (so that I wouldn't have to create objects myself), but OK - here you go.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table box as
  2    select 1 carid, 100 capacity, trunc(sysdate) datum from dual union all
  3    select 2 carid, 200 capacity, trunc(sysdate) datum from dual;

Table created.
```

Types declared at SQL level (not within the PL/SQL code!); `t_box` matches the `box` table, plus additional `c_count`, otherwise you can't put `count(*)` value into it as that column (`amount`, right?) doesn't exist in the table:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_box as object
  2    (carid    number,
  3     capacity number,
  4     datum    date,
  5     c_count  number
  6    );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_boxt as table of t_box;
  2  /

Type created.
```

PL/SQL code: note line #4. Without `t_box(...)`, you'll get your old "not enough values" error (try and see for yourself):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_possiblebox t_boxt;
  3  begin
  4    select t_box(b.carid, b.capacity, b.datum, count(*))   --> you miss T_BOX()
  5      bulk collect into v_possiblebox
  6      from box b
  7      group by b.carid, b.capacity, b.datum;
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Count = ' || v_possiblebox.count);
  9  end;
 10  /
Count = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now it *works*.

Comment: Thank you for your example, it helped me a lot to understand where my mistake was.